# Facebook Graph returns empty "likes" array for some users who have likes

Tags: arrays, facebook, graph

Facebook Graph returns empty "likes" array for some users who have likes. I added the friends_likes permission and works fine for most of users but for some of them (who i checked and have likes) returns an empty array. Why is this happening? Hot to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

No, I am having the same problem, and I can tell for sure that the user in question (user B who is a friend of user A) doesn't have any custom privacy settings.

user A game friends_likes permissions,
still when I lookup `graph.facebook.com/<userB_id>/likes` I get an empty array,
same for `graph.facebook.com/likes/?id=<userB-id>`.

Answer (score 1):

They most likely have custom privacy on their likes, blocked your app, or opted-out or disabled the Facebook development platform.

Comment: lol, simultaneous posting.  But your answer is more indepth because the friend could have opted out or blocked the app. Removing mine.